# php - Magento 1 - Static blocks not appearing on frontend after db save

Tags: php, magento, caching, block

I have a script in which I replace the old content of the blocks with something else. At the end I just call $block->setContent($content)->save(). The issue is that after i run the script and the new content is save to the db, I still have to manually go into the admin and click Save on the block in order for it to appear

I've tried flushing the caches multiple times